# Rounding Doubles to int C#

Tags: c#, wpf, precision

I want to calcuate the distance of a BorderControl to the Grid in which it is added, but in rounded percentage.

I use this method:

```
internal static tPosition GetControlTPosition(Border tempInnerControl, Grid tempOuterGrid)
    {
        tPosition tempTPosition = new tPosition();

        Point tempInnerControlCornerPoint = tempInnerControl.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

        Point tempOuterGridCornerPoint = tempOuterGrid.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

        //
        //Top Left Corner
        //Fist we calculate the Distance of the Top left Corners of both elements
        double distanceLeft = tempInnerControlCornerPoint.X - tempOuterGridCornerPoint.X;
        double distanceTop = tempInnerControlCornerPoint.Y - tempOuterGridCornerPoint.Y;

        //Then we set the percentage of our position accordingly
        tempTPosition.PositionLeft = (int)(((distanceLeft) * 100 / tempOuterGrid.ActualWidth));
        tempTPosition.PositionTop = (int)((distanceTop) * 100 / tempOuterGrid.ActualHeight);

        //
        // Bottom Right Corner
        //Now we calculate the distance of the bottom right corner to the outher grids bottom right corner
        double distanceRight =  (tempOuterGridCornerPoint.X + tempOuterGrid.ActualWidth) - (tempInnerControlCornerPoint.X + tempInnerControl.ActualWidth);
        double distanceBottom = (tempOuterGridCornerPoint.Y + tempOuterGrid.ActualHeight) - (tempInnerControlCornerPoint.Y + tempInnerControl.ActualHeight);

        tempTPosition.PositionRight = (int)((distanceRight)*100/tempOuterGrid.ActualWidth);
        tempTPosition.PositionBottom = (int)((distanceBottom) * 100 / tempOuterGrid.ActualHeight);

        return tempTPosition;
    }
```

My problem is that the BorderControl keeps getting bigger, meaning there is a problem with the percentages being to low, i guess this happen because i lose precision. How can i avoid this?

I need the numbers as int, for various reasons.

tPosition is just left,top,right,bottom as ints

Comment: Hmm, why are you doing something like this? Wouldn't it be better to let it be handled by the standard WPF mechanism?

Comment: im writing an editor for something, in it you can drag pictures around on a background, those pictures are set by percentage to the total backgroundsize (the outer grid), for scalability. Now this method is called after a picture has been moved, so i can get its position, and i don't know of a better way to get the position and convert it in percentage.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely lose your precision when finding tempTPosition, instead of using double as you have been you are using int, which will round the value to a whole number

try it with doubles

```
//Then we set the percentage of our position accordingly
    tempTPosition.PositionLeft = (double)(((distanceLeft) * 100 / tempOuterGrid.ActualWidth));
    tempTPosition.PositionTop = (double)((distanceTop) * 100 / tempOuterGrid.ActualHeight);
```

Remember to also do this for PositionRight & PositionBottom

Comment: "I want to calcuate the distance of a BorderControl to the Grid in which it is added, but in rounded percentage." But i need the values as complete numbers, ints. Doubles will make more problems later, i know that i lose at that point, so i want to round them. But i get the problem that it gets smaller on both sides.

Comment: For example, my innerControl was at 5,5,5,5 in the beginning. Now i drag it a bit to the top/left, use this method to get its new percentage and receive: 2,2,7,7, which does not add up. It should be eitehr 3,3,7,7 or 2,2,8,8.

Comment: You may have to make that sacrifise of precision by using int throughout if you are struggling to convert. You are losing precision when you are converting between the two different types. Other then that i have little clue, i am quite new to programming.

Comment: its not a issue of losing precision, its an issue of wrong rounding, for example if i get both at 1,5 i need one to go down to 1 and one to go up to 2, that would make it correct.